# $HOME is forgotten only when a remote SSHed "screen" session is detached

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, irssi

Whenever I detach my remote "screen" session and ctrl a-c a new window, it opens the new window with "/" as the PWD. Another extremely annoying problem is that whenever the "screen" session is detached, the IRSSI IRC client cannot find the log files to write into them. It mostly happens with private messages.

This only happens when the "screen" is detached and goes away when I attach again.

The remote computer is running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: How can you "ctrl a-c a new window" in a detached session?

Comment: What filesystem your home directory is in? Is it an ordinary local filesystem, or encrypted (eCryptFS/EncFS), or remote (AFS/NFS/Samba)? (Use `df -T ~` to find out.) Does it happen always when you detach (C-a d) or only when you close the SSH connection entirely? (If it's a secure network filesystem and you close SSH, the server might be destroying the keys used to access it.)

Comment: @grawity, it happens when I reattach and "ctrl a-c". It is an encrypted local filesystem shipped with Ubuntu. If the screen session is detached and still works in the background, the encrypted home directory won't be closed.

Comment: @Yuval: Over the *same* SSH connection or a different one?

Comment: When all logins exit, the keys are forgotten. Should have mentioned it earlier. It's an headless machine. When I boot, the home directory isn't immediately available after I ssh to my account. I have to use "ecryptfs-mount-private" first to unlock it.

Comment: @grawity, I should have notified you by the @ thing.